# inline theorems and theorems within captions

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, theorems

I'm trying write a paper where I have a sequence of autonumbered pieces of inline quotes.

I defined a `\newcommand` to do this and all worked well until the point that I tried to save the current number to a variable so I could then refer to it, e.g. in a Table. Obviously `\label` picks up the current section so that didn't work. If `\label` took a second argument so that one could write `\label{mylabel}{mycounter}` then that would be perfect, but `\label` only seems to take one argument.

I tried to amend my newcommand so that it defined (using `\def` or `\newcommand`) a new label (passed as an additional argument to the command each time it was called, but I always got syntax errors).  At present I've reverted to using a theorem environment but that has two problems (1) it means the text is not inline but separated from surrounding text by newlines, and secondly it doesn't seem to be possible to put a theorem inside a figure caption.  I've tried using `\savebox` for the latter but that didn't seem to work either.

Any help gratefully accepted!  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a minimum working example (MWE) where we can see an example of what you are doing. This should be (1) minimal, i.e. is not bloated with unrelated stuff, (2) complete, i.e. starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, (3) compilable as is and (4) show what you are doing. This will help us to help you.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to think of embedded quotes as theorem objects, which by their nature are set off.  A more productive approach might be to figure out how to have a new counter recognized as an anchor for a label.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the two responses. I couldn't figure out how to go further with the second suggestions, but more googling meanwhile has led me to the `etoolbox` package and I now have a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{promptcounter}

\setcounter{promptcounter}{0}

\def\prompt#1#2{\addtocounter{promptcounter}{1}\csdef{#1}{\thepromptcounter}\underline{Prompt-\thepromptcounter:  }{\textcolor{teal}{\emph{#2}}}}
\begin{document}

This is a test document. \\prompt\{x\}\{y\} should expand to \textcolor{red}{Prompt-1: y} but also define \\x to be the value of {\textbackslash}thepromptcounter.

\prompt{xxx}{some text}.  The value of {\textbackslash}xxx is \xxx. The use of {\textbackslash}etoolbox and {\textbackslash}csdef was critical - it gives an error with plain {\textbackslash}def. 

End of test document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Glad you got your question answered and know the powerful `etoolbox` package now. In the future, if you click the `{}` button or put three ``` (to the left of the number 1 on a QWERTY keyboard) around your code it formats it as a code block :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately I wrote too soon.  I didn't test with a second call of \prompt.   \xxx is defined (of course, now that I think about it) as the string "\thepromptcounter" rather than the value of that string.  So the value inserted by  \xxx changes after each call to \prompt.  Is there a way to force the expansion of a macro within a macro definition?

Comment: Answering my own question: \csdef should be \csedef to force the expansion of \thepromptcounter, otherwise the variable defined always gives as its value the most recent value of \thepromptcounter.